# How i can to delete record when import file using django-import-export?

Tags: django, django-import-export

My project use Django framework and installed django-import-export plugin. I can import and export everything normally. But when i imported file to database. All new records from file upload was imported successfully. but old record that is not in the new records not delete.

### old data in database

```
ID , Name , wage
1 , Mr.A , 100
2 , Mr.B , 110
3 , Mr.C , 150
```

### new file upload

```
ID , Name , wage
1 , Mr.A , 100
2 , Mr.B , 150
4 , Mr.D , 130
```

### the result when imported

```
ID , Name , wage
1 , Mr.A , 100
2 , Mr.B , 150
3 , Mr.C , 150  # < this not delete
4 , Mr.D , 130
```

I want it to be like this in database.

```
----------
ID , Name , wage
1 , Mr.A , 100
2 , Mr.B , 150
4 , Mr.D , 130
```

How i can to delete old record when imported using django-import-export plugins?

here my code

```
class PersonalResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Personal
        import_id_fields = ('p_id',)
        

class PersonalAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = PersonalResource
    list_display = ['p_id','name','poistion','dept']
    search_fields = ['p_id']
```

Comment: You will have to manually check each entry against DB if it exist or not, and delete/modify it according to your data.

Comment: how the best way for manual check please advise me.

Comment: Post your model and the code responsible for processing.

Comment: Thanks, the code is in my post. I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-import-export` won't do this for you by default, but you can easily add some hooks to achieve this.

You can track the id of each row imported or updated, and then delete any others at the end of the import.

for example:

```py
class PersonalResource(resources.ModelResource):
    instances_to_keep = set()

    def after_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        self.instances_to_keep.add(instance.id)

    def after_import(self, dataset, result, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        Personal.objects.exclude(id__in=self.instances_to_keep).delete()

    class Meta:
        model = Personal
        import_id_fields = ('p_id',)
```

Some points to note:

- Read up on the implications of [delete()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete)
- You might consider running this in a [transaction](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import_workflow.html?highlight=transaction#transaction-support) for smaller datasets.